# Show that $G$ is not Hamiltonian.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

> Suppose that $G$ is a graph with $pq$ vertices where $p$ and $q$ are primes and $2<p<q$.
>
> If $(p-1)(q-1)$ vertices of $G$ have degree $p+q-1$ and all other vertices have degree $pq-1$, show that $G$ is not Hamiltonian.

I could just take $(p-1)(q-1)=\phi(pq)$ where $\phi$ is Euler-Totient Function.

But I dont know any conditions to show that a graph is Non-Hamiltonian?

Are there any way to show that a graph is Non-Hamiltonian?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A \subseteq V(G)$ be the set of vertices with degree $p+q-1$, and $B \subseteq V(G)$ be the set of vertices with degree $pq-1$. There are $pq - |A| = pq - (p-1)(q-1) = p+q+1$ vertices in $B$, and having degree $pq-1$ means that they're adjacent to every other vertex. As a result, each vertex in $A$ has $p+q-1$ neighbors in $B$, and cannot be adjacent to anything else.

Therefore, up to isomorphism, for every value of $p$ and $q$, there is only one graph of this type. For example, here is the graph for $p=3$ and $q=5$, with $A$ in red and $B$ in blue:

[image]

Now you should try to show that this graph is not Hamiltonian.

A common general approach is to check that a graph is not [tough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_toughness). A graph is tough when removing any $k$ vertices leaves at most $k$ connected components, and all Hamiltonian graphs are tough (though not all tough graphs are Hamiltonian).

You can also make the argument directly, without invoking toughness; just think about what a hypothetical Hamiltonian cycle would need to do in order to visit every vertex in $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand how to make an argument directly?

Comment: Try to draw a Hamiltonian cycle, think about the reason you fail, and see if you can generalize it.

Comment: I started from an arbitrary vertex and then tried to go to the different vertices but the problem is there are so many edges that I am getting lost

Comment: Are there any theorems which can prove that it is not hamiltonian? dont you think that it will only be a trial and error method

Comment: I suggested one particular theorem already in my answer.

Comment: But the problem is i am not getting how to use the theorem to prove it

Comment: Find a set of $k$ vertices to remove that would leave more than $k$ connected components.

Comment: I am thinking of removing the vertices of $B$ so that we are left with the vertices of $A$ only

Comment: Is it right to remove $B$ vertices? How to prove it directly